# Beta Regression, "phi" as logistic model

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glm

I am conducting a beta - regression in R, using the package "betareg" (version 3.0-3). For a Monte Carlo simulation, I would like to model the dispersion - parameter "phi" as a logit model. Unfortunately, the package does not support the link function "logit" for phi. I have seen that it is possible to supply a self written "glm - link" object, but I do not know how to do this. Does anyone know, how I could solve my problem and model "phi" as a logistic model.

```
betareg(formula, data, subset, na.action, weights, offset,
        link = c("logit", "probit","cloglog", "cauchit", "log", "loglog"),
        link.phi = NULL, type = c("ML", "BC", "BR"),
        control = betareg.control(...), model = TRUE,y = TRUE, x = FALSE, ...)
```

link.phi:
character specification of the link function in the precision model (phi). **Currently, "identity", "log", "sqrt" are supported.** The default is "log" unless formula is of type y ~ x where the default is "identity" (for backward compatibility). Alternatively, an object of class "link-glm" can be supplied.

---

Comment: I wonder if you could modify the Bayesian code presented here to achieve what you want: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41536/how-can-i-model-a-proportion-with-bugs-jags-stan